# Here i am applying model validation and I want to stop post my form but its not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My form Code on which i am trying:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ContactUs", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmContactUs", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <div class="form_style">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @placeholder = "Name", @class = "inputType" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_style">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email", @class = "inputType" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_style">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @placeholder = "Message", @class = "inputType texArea", @style = "resize: none" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_style">
                        <input type="submit" class="inputType Sub_btn" id="btnContactUs" value="SUBMIT" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnContactUs" value="@Url.Action("ContactUs", "Home")" />
                }
```

jquery ajax call Script:

```
var url = $('#hdnContactUs').val();
var Name = $('#Name').val();
var Email = $('#Email').val();
var Message = $('#Message').val();
$("frmContactUs").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { name: Name, email: Email, message: Message },
        success: function (data) {
            showMsg(data);
            return false;
        },
        cache: false
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

here i want model validation but i do not want to post my form, currently its post to my controller jsonresult:

```
 public JsonResult ContactUs(string Name, string Email, string Message)
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Hard to understand what your doing here. What is the purpose of the script - it will only ever post the initial values of your controls (not the edited values). And since you have included `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for all the properties, the form wont submit anyway if the properties are invalid and you have included the relevant scripts (jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have `$("frmContactUs")` instead of `$("#frmContactUs")`. You forgot the `#` from id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#frmContactUs").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
             $(form).ajaxSubmit();
     }
});
```

Hope this will help you.
read this [**jqueryvalidation**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)